# cannot install ros electric source (Checkout problem, after uninstalling)

Tags: ros, installation, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I had a mess because I installed the source and binary electric ros versions. I tried to take everything out and install the source version again, but it does not work. It says there is a problem with the version checkout. What can it be? (I removed everythin ros-el* in apt-get and the source folder ~/ros).

I tried to install the full version. This is what I get:

---

---

```
:~$ rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=electric&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no"
rosinstall operating on /home/dlr/ros from specifications in rosinstall files  http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=electric&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no
(Over-)Writing /home/dlr/ros/.rosinstall
[ros] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros/tags/ros-1.6.8 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/ros
[ros_comm] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_comm/tags/ros_comm-1.6.6 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/ros_comm
[common_rosdeps] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/common/rosdepcore (common_rosdeps-1.0.2) to /home/dlr/ros/common_rosdeps
[bond_core] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/common/bondcore (bond_core-1.6.1) to /home/dlr/ros/bond_core
[common_msgs] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/common_msgs/tags/common_msgs-1.6.0 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/common_msgs
[common] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/common/common (common-1.6.1) to /home/dlr/ros/common
[diagnostics] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/diagnostics/tags/diagnostics-1.6.2 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/diagnostics
[driver_common] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/driver_common/tags/driver_common-1.2.4 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/driver_common
[eigen] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/eigen (eigen-1.6.0) to /home/dlr/ros/eigen
[bullet] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/bullet (bullet-2.76.5) to /home/dlr/ros/bullet
[geometry] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/geometry (geometry-1.6.1) to /home/dlr/ros/geometry
[nodelet_core] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/common/nodeletcore (nodelet_core-1.6.2) to /home/dlr/ros/nodelet_core
[orocos_kinematics_dynamics] Installing http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/robotics/orocos_kinematics_dynamics.git (orocos_kinematics_dynamics-0.2.3) to /home/dlr/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
[robot_model] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/robot_model (robot_model-1.6.4) to /home/dlr/ros/robot_model
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dlr/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/.git/
[pluginlib] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/common/pluginlib (pluginlib-1.6.0) to /home/dlr/ros/pluginlib
[executive_smach] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/smach/executive_smach (executive_smach-1.0.4) to /home/dlr/ros/executive_smach
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
[simulator_gazebo] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/simulator_gazebo-1.4.12 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/simulator_gazebo
[simulator_stage] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_stage/tags/simulator_stage-1.4.0 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/simulator_stage
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
[stage] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/stage/tags/stage-1.4.1 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/stage
[physics_ode] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/physics_ode/tags/physics_ode-1.6.1 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/physics_ode
[visualization_common] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/visualization_common/tags/visualization_common-1.6.2 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/visualization_common
[rx] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/rx/tags/rx-1.6.1 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/rx
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
[filters] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/common/filters (filters-1.6.0) to /home/dlr/ros/filters
[assimp] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/assimp (assimp-0.1.1) to /home/dlr/ros/assimp
[laser_pipeline] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/laser_pipeline/tags/laser_pipeline-1.2.1 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/laser_pipeline
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
[diagnostics_monitors] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/diagnostics_monitors/tags/diagnostics_monitors-1.4.1 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/diagnostics_monitors
[image_common] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/image_common/tags/image_common-1.6.1 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/image_common
[geometry_visualization] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/visualization (geometry_visualization-0.1.1) to /home/dlr/ros/geometry_visualization
[perception_pcl] Installing http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/tags/perception_pcl-1.0.2 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/perception_pcl
[visualization] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/visualization/tags/visualization-1.6.7 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/visualization
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
[image_transport_plugins] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/image_transport_plugins/tags/image_transport_plugins-1.4.2 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/image_transport_plugins
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
[xacro] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/common/xacro (xacro-1.6.0) to /home/dlr/ros/xacro
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
[vision_opencv] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vision_opencv/tags/vision_opencv-1.6.9 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/vision_opencv
[navigation] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/navigation/navigation (navigation-1.6.5) to /home/dlr/ros/navigation
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
[image_pipeline] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/image_pipeline/tags/image_pipeline-1.6.4 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/image_pipeline
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
[slam_gmapping] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/slam_gmapping/tags/slam_gmapping-1.2.5 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/slam_gmapping
[robot_model_visualization] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/visualization (robot_model_visualization-0.1.2) to /home/dlr/ros/robot_model_visualization
[ros_tutorials] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_tutorials/tags/ros_tutorials-0.2.6 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/ros_tutorials
[executive_smach_visualization] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/smach/visualization (executive_smach_visualization-1.0.2) to /home/dlr/ros/executive_smach_visualization
[geometry_experimental] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/experimental (geometry_experimental-0.2.2) to /home/dlr/ros/geometry_experimental
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
[documentation] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/documentation/tags/documentation-1.4.3 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/documentation
[geometry_tutorials] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/tutorials (geometry_tutorials-0.1.3) to /home/dlr/ros/geometry_tutorials
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
[visualization_tutorials] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/visualization_tutorials/tags/visualization_tutorials-0.4.0 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/visualization_tutorials
[common_tutorials] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/common_tutorials/tags/common_tutorials-0.1.2 (None) to /home/dlr/ros/common_tutorials
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
[robot_model_tutorials] Installing https://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/tutorials (robot_model_tutorials-0.1.2) to /home/dlr/ros/robot_model_tutorials
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
svn: 'None' does not appear to be a URL
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 10 changesets with 11 changes to 5 files
updating to branch default
4 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[assimp] Done.
adding changesets
adding changesets
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 86 changesets with 86 changes to 6 files (+2 heads)
adding changesets
updating to branch default
5 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
adding changesets
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
5 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
added 33 changesets with 45 changes to 10 files
[common_rosdeps] Done.
updating to branch xacro
10 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 23 changesets with 74 changes to 37 files
updating to branch cpp_separation
2 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[xacro] Done.
37 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
adding changesets
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[filters] Done.
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 12 changesets with 28 changes to 17 files
updating to branch default
17 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[geometry_tutorials] Done.
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 64 changesets with 138 changes to 61 files (+1 heads)
updating to branch default
51 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
adding manifests
adding file changes
adding manifests
adding file changes
4 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
added 40 changesets with 113 changes to 61 files
[executive_smach] Done.
updating to branch default
13 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[executive_smach_visualization] Done.
added 58 changesets with 205 changes to 135 files
updating to branch default
134 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
adding manifests
adding file changes
adding manifests
adding file changes
6 files updated, 0 files merged, 2 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[pluginlib] Done.
adding changesets
adding changesets
adding changesets
adding changesets
adding changesets
added 18 changesets with 68 changes to 54 files
updating to branch default
9 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
adding changesets
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[robot_model_visualization] Done.
added 18 changesets with 68 changes to 54 files
updating to branch default
27 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
adding changesets
adding changesets
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
adding changesets
[robot_model_tutorials] Done.
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding manifests
adding file changes
adding file changes
adding manifests
adding manifests
adding file changes
adding manifests
adding file changes
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 524 changesets with 1203 changes to 457 files (+4 heads)
adding manifests
updating to branch default
48 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
6 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[bond_core] Done.
adding manifests
added 548 changesets with 1264 changes to 464 files (+4 heads)
adding file changes
adding manifests
updating to branch default
52 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
adding file changes
16 files updated, 0 files merged, 6 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[nodelet_core] Done.
adding manifests
adding file changes
adding file changes
adding file changes
added 993 changesets with 1673 changes to 386 files (+15 heads)
updating to branch default
10 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
14 files updated, 0 files merged, 2 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[bullet] Done.
added 911 changesets with 1579 changes to 373 files (+13 heads)
updating to branch default
14 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
added 974 changesets with 1639 changes to 372 files (+15 heads)
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[geometry_visualization] Done.
updating to branch default
140 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
added 576 changesets with 1291 changes to 461 files (+5 heads)
6 files updated, 0 files merged, 136 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[eigen] Done.
updating to branch default
5 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
114 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[common] Done.
added 976 changesets with 1645 changes to 364 files (+14 heads)
added 1063 changesets with 1831 changes to 398 files (+15 heads)
updating to branch default
116 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
updating to branch default
106 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
8 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[geometry_experimental] Done.
33 files updated, 0 files merged, 11 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[geometry] Done.
added 425 changesets with 935 changes to 280 files (+5 heads)
updating to branch default
178 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
10 files updated, 0 files merged, 11 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[robot_model] Done.
added 755 changesets with 1814 changes to 560 files (+14 heads)
updating to branch default
231 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
40 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[navigation] Done.
Switched to a new branch 'rosinstall_tagged_branch'
[orocos_kinematics_dynamics] Done.
ERROR in config: Error during install of 'ros' : [ros] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros/tags/ros-1.6.8 version None into /home/dlr/ros/ros failed.
Error during install of 'ros_comm' : [ros_comm] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_comm/tags/ros_comm-1.6.6 version None into /home/dlr/ros/ros_comm failed.
Error during install of 'common_msgs' : [common_msgs] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/common_msgs/tags/common_msgs-1.6.0 version None into /home/dlr/ros/common_msgs failed.
Error during install of 'diagnostics' : [diagnostics] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/diagnostics/tags/diagnostics-1.6.2 version None into /home/dlr/ros/diagnostics failed.
Error during install of 'driver_common' : [driver_common] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/driver_common/tags/driver_common-1.2.4 version None into /home/dlr/ros/driver_common failed.
Error during install of 'simulator_stage' : [simulator_stage] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_stage/tags/simulator_stage-1.4.0 version None into /home/dlr/ros/simulator_stage failed.
Error during install of 'simulator_gazebo' : [simulator_gazebo] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/simulator_gazebo-1.4.12 version None into /home/dlr/ros/simulator_gazebo failed.
Error during install of 'stage' : [stage] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/stage/tags/stage-1.4.1 version None into /home/dlr/ros/stage failed.
Error during install of 'physics_ode' : [physics_ode] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/physics_ode/tags/physics_ode-1.6.1 version None into /home/dlr/ros/physics_ode failed.
Error during install of 'visualization_common' : [visualization_common] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/visualization_common/tags/visualization_common-1.6.2 version None into /home/dlr/ros/visualization_common failed.
Error during install of 'rx' : [rx] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/rx/tags/rx-1.6.1 version None into /home/dlr/ros/rx failed.
Error during install of 'image_common' : [image_common] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/image_common/tags/image_common-1.6.1 version None into /home/dlr/ros/image_common failed.
Error during install of 'perception_pcl' : [perception_pcl] Checkout of http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/tags/perception_pcl-1.0.2 version None into /home/dlr/ros/perception_pcl failed.
Error during install of 'image_transport_plugins' : [image_transport_plugins] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/image_transport_plugins/tags/image_transport_plugins-1.4.2 version None into /home/dlr/ros/image_transport_plugins failed.
Error during install of 'image_pipeline' : [image_pipeline] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/image_pipeline/tags/image_pipeline-1.6.4 version None into /home/dlr/ros/image_pipeline failed.
Error during install of 'laser_pipeline' : [laser_pipeline] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/laser_pipeline/tags/laser_pipeline-1.2.1 version None into /home/dlr/ros/laser_pipeline failed.
Error during install of 'vision_opencv' : [vision_opencv] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vision_opencv/tags/vision_opencv-1.6.9 version None into /home/dlr/ros/vision_opencv failed.
Error during install of 'slam_gmapping' : [slam_gmapping] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/slam_gmapping/tags/slam_gmapping-1.2.5 version None into /home/dlr/ros/slam_gmapping failed.
Error during install of 'visualization' : [visualization] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/visualization/tags/visualization-1.6.7 version None into /home/dlr/ros/visualization failed.
Error during install of 'diagnostics_monitors' : [diagnostics_monitors] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/diagnostics_monitors/tags/diagnostics_monitors-1.4.1 version None into /home/dlr/ros/diagnostics_monitors failed.
Error during install of 'documentation' : [documentation] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/documentation/tags/documentation-1.4.3 version None into /home/dlr/ros/documentation failed.
Error during install of 'ros_tutorials' : [ros_tutorials] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_tutorials/tags/ros_tutorials-0.2.6 version None into /home/dlr/ros/ros_tutorials failed.
Error during install of 'common_tutorials' : [common_tutorials] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/common_tutorials/tags/common_tutorials-0.1.2 version None into /home/dlr/ros/common_tutorials failed.
Error during install of 'visualization_tutorials' : [visualization_tutorials] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/visualization_tutorials/tags/visualization_tutorials-0.4.0 version None into /home/dlr/ros/visualization_tutorials failed.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29432/cannot-install-ros-electric-source-(checkout-problem,-after-uninstalling)/) by [cduguet](https://answers.ros.org/users/1941/cduguet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 187 on 2012-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I moved to ubuntu 11.10, and althought this has nothing to do with the problem, I installed ROS from source on a clean ubuntu installation. I am sorry not to post the anwer to your question, but I needed ROS working ASAP. I'll keep an eze on vcstools whenever I'm having this problem again.

---

Originally posted by [cduguet](https://answers.ros.org/users/1941/cduguet/) with karma: 187 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, this may have been a bug in vcstools version 0.1.7, it is already fixed in 0.1.8. Please update vcstools.

Actually I could not reproduce your error even with that version, could you run rosinstall --version if the error persist and post the result?

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure to update vcstools by either running
sudo pip install -U rosinstall
or
sudo easy_install -U rosinstall vcstools

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2012-03-13**:
@KruseT It fixed mots of the problems reported above in my case. However I still have this: `ERROR in config: Error processing 'nodelet_core' : [nodelet_core] Checkout of https://kforge.ros.org/common/nodeletcore version nodelet_core-1.6.2 into /Users/luca/Software/ros/electric/nodelet_core failed.`